# How to do antilog in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, arima

I am new to Python and data analysis, O am working on time series problem using ARIMA model. Suppose my data is

```
Month,Value
1949-01,112
1949-02,118
1949-03,132
1949-04,129
1949-05,121
1949-06,135
1949-07,148
1949-08,148
1949-09,136
```

and on basis of above data I have to predict next years data, I am able to do that all concept is taken form [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8Yw4alG16Q), but in the end the results are in the form of ***log*** and I want to convert it in the form of number of passengers.

My code

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
from pyspark.sql.functions import window
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from unicodedata import decomposition


rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 6

dataset = pd.read_csv("/home/rajnish.kumar/eclipse-workspace/TimeSeriesPrediction/Data/trial_series.csv")

# parse strings to datetime type
dataset['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Month'], infer_datetime_format=True)
indexedDataset = dataset.set_index(['Month'])


print(indexedDataset.tail())

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("value")

plt.plot(indexedDataset)
plt.show()

rolemean = indexedDataset.rolling(window=12).mean()

rolstd = indexedDataset.rolling(window=12).std()

print(rolemean,rolstd)

orign = plt.plot(indexedDataset,color='blue',label='Original')
meanplot = plt.plot(rolemean,color='red',label='Roling Mean')
std = plt.plot(rolstd,color='black',label='Rolling Std')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title("Rolling Mean and Standard Deviation")
plt.show(block=False)



print("Result of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
dftest = adfuller(indexedDataset['Value'], autolag='AIC')
dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value','#Lags Used','Number Of Observations Used'])

for key, value in dftest[4].items():
    dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key]= value

print(dfoutput)

indexedDataset_logScale = np.log(indexedDataset)
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale)



movingaverage = indexedDataset_logScale.rolling(window=12).mean()
movingSTD = indexedDataset_logScale.rolling(window=12).std()

plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale)
plt.plot(movingaverage,color='red')


dataSetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage = indexedDataset_logScale - movingaverage
print(dataSetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage.head(12))

# remove NAN Values

dataSetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage.dropna(inplace=True)

print(dataSetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage.head(10))




def test_stationarity(timeseries):
    movingAverage = timeseries.rolling(window=12).mean()
    movingSTD = timeseries.rolling(window=12).std()

    orign = plt.plot(timeseries,color='blue',label='Original')
    meanplot = plt.plot(movingAverage,color='red',label='Roling Mean')
    std = plt.plot(movingSTD,color='black',label='Rolling Std')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title("Rolling Mean and Standard Deviation")
    plt.show(block=False)


    dftest = adfuller(timeseries['Value'], autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value','#Lags Used','Number Of Observations Used'])

    for key, value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key]= value


    print(dfoutput)


test_stationarity(dataSetLogScaleMinusMovingAverage)


exponentialDecayWeightedAverage = indexedDataset_logScale.ewm(halflife=12,min_periods=0,adjust= True).mean()
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale)
plt.plot(exponentialDecayWeightedAverage,color='red')


datasetLogScaleMinusMovingExponentialDecayAverage = indexedDataset_logScale - exponentialDecayWeightedAverage
test_stationarity(datasetLogScaleMinusMovingExponentialDecayAverage)


datasetLogDiffShifting = indexedDataset_logScale - indexedDataset_logScale.shift()
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)

datasetLogDiffShifting.dropna(inplace=True)
test_stationarity(datasetLogDiffShifting)


from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

decomposition = seasonal_decompose(indexedDataset_logScale)

trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = decomposition.resid


plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(indexedDataset_logScale,label='Original')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(412)
plt.plot(trend,label='Trend')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(413)
plt.plot(seasonal,label='Seasonality')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(414)
plt.plot(residual,label='Residuals')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.tight_layout()


decomposedLogData = residual
decomposedLogData.dropna(inplace=True)
test_stationarity(decomposedLogData)



# ACF and PACF  plots


from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf,pacf

lag_acf = acf(datasetLogDiffShifting,nlags=20)
lag_pacf = pacf(datasetLogDiffShifting,nlags=20,method='ols')

# Plot ACF
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(lag_acf)
plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.axhline(y= 1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.title('Autocorrelation Function')


# Plot PACF
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(lag_pacf)
plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.axhline(y= 1.96/np.sqrt(len(datasetLogDiffShifting)),linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.title('PArtial Autocorrelation Function')
plt.tight_layout()



from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

# AR MODEL
model = ARIMA (indexedDataset_logScale,order =(2,1,2))
results_ar = model.fit(disp=1)
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)
plt.plot(results_ar.fittedvalues,color ='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_ar.fittedvalues-datasetLogDiffShifting["Value"])**2))
print('Plotting AR Model')

# MA MODEL

Model = ARIMA (indexedDataset_logScale,order =(0,1,2))
results_ma = Model.fit(disp=1)
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)
plt.plot(results_ma.fittedvalues,color ='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_ma.fittedvalues-datasetLogDiffShifting["Value"])**2))
print('Plotting MA Model')


# ARIMA

MoDel = ARIMA (indexedDataset_logScale,order =(2,1,2))
results_arima = MoDel.fit(disp=1)
plt.plot(datasetLogDiffShifting)
plt.plot(results_arima.fittedvalues,color ='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_arima.fittedvalues-datasetLogDiffShifting["Value"])**2))
print('Plotting ARIMA Model')



predictions_ARIMA_diff = pd.Series(results_arima.fittedvalues,copy=True)
print(predictions_ARIMA_diff.head())

# Convert to cumulative sum

predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum = predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum()
print(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum.head())


predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(indexedDataset_logScale['Value'].ix[0],index=indexedDataset_logScale.index)
predictions_ARIMA_log = predictions_ARIMA_log.add(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum,fill_value=0)
print(predictions_ARIMA_log.head())

predictions_ARIMA = np.exp(predictions_ARIMA_log)
plt.plot(indexedDataset)
plt.plot(predictions_ARIMA)

# predict

results_arima.plot_predict(1,264)
#predictions_ARIMA.forecast(steps=12)


print "-------------------------------------"
print predictions_ARIMA.forecast(steps=12)  // when i run this line i am getting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rajnish.kumar/eclipse-workspace/TimeSeriesPrediction/TimeSerise/__init__.py", line 227, in <module>
    predictions_ARIMA.forecast(steps=12)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'forecast'
```

and when i run `print results_arima.forecast(steps=12)` i am getting below result.

```
(array([ 6.09553392,  6.1528141 ,  6.22442983,  6.29241129,  6.34164751,
        6.36359397,  6.35784715,  6.33139323,  6.29597547,  6.2644771 ,
        6.24738318,  6.25025166]), array([ 0.08384711,  0.10749464,  0.11568698,  0.11702779,  0.11703501,
        0.11744022,  0.11762254,  0.11778717,  0.12024167,  0.12736047,
        0.13870965,  0.15118799]), array([[ 5.9311966 ,  6.25987125],
       [ 5.94212847,  6.36349972],
       [ 5.99768751,  6.45117214],
       [ 6.06304103,  6.52178154],
       [ 6.11226311,  6.5710319 ],
       [ 6.13341538,  6.59377256],
       [ 6.12731121,  6.58838309],
       [ 6.10053461,  6.56225184],
       [ 6.06030613,  6.5316448 ],
       [ 6.01485518,  6.51409903],
       [ 5.97551726,  6.5192491 ],
       [ 5.95392864,  6.54657468]]))
```

Comment: could you give an example of the data that you want to transform?

Comment: @ Jones1220  please download data form here https://github.com/aarshayj/Analytics_Vidhya/tree/master/Articles/Time_Series_Analysis (data is air passenger)

Comment: In the last result it is giving me the expected result but not in the form of passengers ,how to convert the predictions in passengers format please help

Answer (score 4):

The inverse of log is exp, which NumPy has: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html

Answer (score 3):

In the last block of the notebook on GitHub, the author is transforming the logs back to the numbers of passengers using the numpy method that @John Zwinck suggests:

```
predictions_ARIMA = np.exp(predictions_ARIMA_log)
```

**EDIT:**

You can transform your given result with a nested list comprehension:

```
results = results_arima.forecast(steps=12)    
converted_results = [(np.exp(x)) for x in [i for i in results]]
```

Comment: @ Jones1220 but that dosent prints results in the form of passengers  ?

Comment: did you run the notebook? In the last section it converts the data to its original scale